# Opening a PDF file in anew web view from a button

Tags: swift, xcode, pdf

I am trying to open a PDF file within my app. But I keep getting the following error when I click on the button in the simulator.

> 2019-07-31 14:11:39.542087+1000 TJP:Photography Training[4508:715096]
>   Unknown class _TtC24TJP_Photography_Training10AboutAppVC in Interface
>   Builder file. 2019-07-31 14:11:41.020377+1000 TJP:Photography
>   Training[4508:715096] -[UIViewController howToUseTheAppAction:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd6f701d60 2019-07-31
>   14:11:41.024444+1000 TJP:Photography Training[4508:715096] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   howToUseTheAppAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fbd6f701d60'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001066308db **exceptionPreprocess + 331  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000104171ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010664ec94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a4ec235
>   -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106635623 ___forwarding_** + 1443  5   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000106637418 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120    6   UIKitCore
>   0x000000010a4c1624 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>     7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109f168d5
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109f16bf2 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
>     9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109f15ba8
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a4fa4e6 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2547     11 
>   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a4fbbca -[UIWindow
>   sendEvent:] + 4079    12  UIKitCore
>   0x000000010a4da30e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356  13  UIKitCore
>   0x000000010a5aa2b3 **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3232
>     14  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a5acbd9
>   __handleEventQueueInternal + 5911     15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106597db1
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106597633
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243   17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106591cef __CFRunLoopRun + 1231    18  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001065914d2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626     19  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010e7f42fe GSEventRunModal + 65   20  UIKitCore
>   0x000000010a4bffc2 UIApplicationMain + 140    21  TJP:Photography
>   Training            0x00000001038897db main + 75  22  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000107a3d541 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

I followed a youtube tutorial which worked in a project on its on but as soon as tried the same thing in the app I am working on it came up with the above error. I have not done anything differently. I have triple checked all my code and connections for spelling errors.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class AboutAppController: UIViewController {

    let pdfTitle1 = "How to use the App"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func howToUseTheAppAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfTitle1, withExtension: "pdf") {
            let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(urlRequest as URLRequest)

            let pdfVC = UIViewController()
            pdfVC.view.addSubview(webView)
            pdfVC.title = pdfTitle1
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)    }
    }

}
```

I expect for the PDF file to open in a new web view

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your storyboard file. I think you can missing or duplicate IBOulet. even you can forget remove old IBOulet, Which was deleted.

[image]